# Measure the current draw of a motor with a slow multimeter?

Tags: motor, multimeter

I have a motor that is in a printer housing (inkjet - the one that moves the head back and forth). The motor is attached to the printer head assembly. I want to measure the current draw of the motor, but I cannot take it out of the printer assembly without breaking it. I know how to do this with a multimeter, but by the time my multimeter is able to get a reading on the current, the printer head would be at the other end (causing more stress on the motor) and would draw more current than it normally should. Is there any way for me to measure the reading of it while it is moving the printer head?

Comment: An oscilloscope would be the easiest way. You could also cob together a peak-reading circuit from components- an op-amp a few resistors and a diode and a reasonably low-leakage capacitor.

Comment: @spehro i unfortunatly dont have a scops

Comment: Then build a peak detector circuit or borrow a scope.

Answer (score 1):

Put a suitable resistor in series with it and measure the voltage across it with a scope.

Comment: Suitable referring to a very low resistance, just to add to this.

Comment: I dont have a scope - can this be done with a multimeter?

Comment: No, it isn't fast enough.